# Python FFmpeg Video Streaming: hls.output() does not work for live camera capture

Tags: python, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I am trying to capture camera live stream and make HLS stream from it. I am using Fantech Luminous C30 webcam. I get this error:

```
ERROR:root:ffmpeg failed to execute command: b'ffmpeg version 2022-12-11-git-c3e20f78b0-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers\r\n  built with gcc 12.1.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)\r\n 
 configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint\r\n  libavutil      57. 43.100 / 57. 43.100\r\n  libavcodec     59. 55.100 / 59. 55.100\r\n  libavformat    59. 34.102 / 59. 34.102\r\n  libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101\r\n  libavfilter     8. 52.100 /  8. 52.100\r\n  libswscale      6.  8.112 /  6.  8.112\r\n  libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100\r\n  libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100\r\nFantech Luminous C30: No such file or directory\r\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ltadic\Desktop\hls stream\camera_stream.py", line 12, in <module>
    hls.output('C:\\Users\\ltadic\\Desktop\\camera_stream\\hls.m3u8')
  File "C:\Users\ltadic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ffmpeg_streaming\_media.py", line 93, in output
    self.run(ffmpeg_bin, monitor, **options)
  File "C:\Users\ltadic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ffmpeg_streaming\_media.py", line 121, in run  
    asyncio.run(self.async_run(ffmpeg_bin, monitor, **options))
  File "C:\Users\ltadic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ltadic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ltadic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 650, in run_until_complete     
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ltadic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ffmpeg_streaming\_media.py", line 112, in async_run
    self._run(ffmpeg_bin, monitor, **options)
  File "C:\Users\ltadic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ffmpeg_streaming\_media.py", line 106, in _run
    self.pipe, err = process.run()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ltadic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ffmpeg_streaming\_process.py", line 122, in run
    raise RuntimeError('ffmpeg failed to execute command: ', error)
RuntimeError: ('ffmpeg failed to execute command: ', "b'ffmpeg version 2022-12-11-git-c3e20f78b0-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers\\r\\n  built with gcc 12.1.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)\\r\\n  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint\\r\\n  libavutil      57. 43.100 / 57. 43.100\\r\\n  libavcodec     59. 55.100 / 59. 55.100\\r\\n  libavformat    59. 34.102 / 59. 34.102\\r\\n  libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101\\r\\n  libavfilter     8. 52.100 /  8. 52.100\\r\\n  libswscale 
     6.  8.112 /  6.  8.112\\r\\n  libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100\\r\\n  libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100\\r\\nFantech Luminous C30: No such file or directory\\r\\n'")
```

This is my code:

```
import ffmpeg_streaming
from ffmpeg_streaming import Formats,Bitrate, Representation, Size 

video = ffmpeg_streaming.input('Fantech Luminous C30', capture = True)

_360p  = Representation(Size(640, 360), Bitrate(276 * 1024, 128 * 1024))
_480p  = Representation(Size(854, 480), Bitrate(750 * 1024, 192 * 1024))
_720p  = Representation(Size(1280, 720), Bitrate(2048 * 1024, 320 * 1024))

hls = video.hls(Formats.h264())
hls.representations(_360p, _480p, _720p)
hls.output('C:\\Users\\ltadic\\Desktop\\camera_stream\\hls.m3u8')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that FFmpeg reported an error while trying to capture the video from your webcam. There may be a problem with the path or name of the webcam given in the error message: "Fantech Luminous C30: No such file or directory". A possible reason for this error could be that FFmpeg is not able to find the webcam. Make sure that the webcam is connected to your computer and that the driver for the webcam is installed. Make sure FFmpeg is using the correct webcam. It could also be that FFmpeg does not have the required codecs or libraries to capture the video from the webcam. Make sure that FFmpeg is configured and compiled correctly and that all the required libraries are present. Did you tried to open your webcam with other applications?

Comment: Camera works on OBS, you also can encode video with FFmpeg and save it in .mp4. I tried to run code line by line and error shows when I uncomment last line in code.

Comment: Did you tried to change the output folder? ffmpeg runs a command in your terminal and maybe the terminal can't handle "\\". You could use "/" instead.

Comment: I also changed output folder and i tried to use "/" instead, but i get same error. As a result i get only first .m3u8 file which looks like this: #EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=413696,RESOLUTION=640x360,NAME="360"
hls_360p.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=964608,RESOLUTION=854x480,NAME="480"
hls_480p.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2424832,RESOLUTION=1280x720,NAME="720"
hls_720p.m3u8

Comment: Did you tried to run this command in your terminal: "ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy" (for windows)? I can't test it, but for me I needed to change the camera name to "/dev/video0" (linux).

Comment: I fixed the issue. Problem was in ffmpeg_streaming package. Two lines in code requested get method instead of pop.  Another problem that showed is that I can capture only one representation (in other words one quality of video) and save it in .m3u8 manifest.